# CSS: Adding a border changes the background-color (?!)

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<div> <p></p> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div { background-color:green; border-top:1px solid white; }
p { background-color:yellow; height:50px; margin:70px; }
```

**Demo:** http://www.jsfiddle.net/Xy8QF/4/

Why is the area above the yellow paragraph green, and the area bellow it white?

btw I already figured this out, but I thought I'll post this anyway. Consider it a riddle `:)`

---

**Update:** Just to add to the accepted answer:

1. Only vertical margins collapse
2. The margins will not collapse if the outer element (in this case the DIV) has a padding or border

Comment: That's freakin' _weird_!

Comment: That's what happens when a constraint-solving problem is specified by a committee.

Comment: Whoa, I've been breaking my head over this for months! It really annoys me when a `h1` pushes down the entire content area of a website by the `h1`'s margin, creating a gap bwtween the content area and the header/menu...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the margins of two block elements with `position:static` (the default) collapse as per [CSS 2.1 8.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), i.e. the margin is "carried over" to the `body` element. This [demo](http://phihag.de/2011/so/border.html) shows it does not happen with absolutely positioned elements, one of the exceptions (along with a non-`none` border) listed in the aforementioned standard.

Comment: I can't tell you how much time I've spent today banging my head trying to figure out why a margin I'm applying to a UL inside of a simple div isn't working and the inspector isn't telling me anything. I only started searching online when I saw that, when I applied a border to visually see my container, THAT's when the margin took effect.... WTF!!!

Answer (score 1):

Good question. :) You can solve it by giving the div a bottom border, or if you don't want to, by giving it a height of 100%. ;-)

Comment: The question was "Why does this happen?" not "How can I change this?"

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `<p>` is right against the bottom of the enclosing `<div>`.  Since there's nothing constraining the height of the `<div>`, the rendering gives just enough space to fit down to the bottom of the `<p>`.  Any explicit height > 50px will show the bottom.

Yup, on the update, exactly.  The box expands vertically, but not horizonally.  Also, padding puts space on the inside of the box, so the p can't push right up against the bounds.

Read up on the CSS box model, for example here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp
and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

Comment: Exactly the same.  Now, since the div has a bottom border, it's the TOP that's free to expand.

Answer (score 0):

The area above the yellow paragraph as you put it, is not actually above it. The green div contains the yellow paragraph. The yellow paragraph has a margin of 70px, pushing away from the green edges of its container. The yellow paragraph has a height set to it, hence we cannot see the yellow pushing away from the green on the bottom edge.

Comment: Giving the paragraph a height is not the reason that it the margin appears between the top of the paragraph and the top of the div but not the bottom of the paragraph and the bottom of the div. As the question identifies, it is because of the border, and the question was "Why?".

Comment: My answer is not incorrect. It answers your question “Why is the area above the yellow paragraph green, and the area bellow it white?”

Comment: But the height is 50px and the margin is 70px. Even if we set the height to only 5px, the same issue is still present: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Xy8QF/26/